# get the values larger than zero only

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm using C# and I get data from database like this:

```
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT name,company,startdate,enddate,DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),enddate) AS days FROM Person", cn);
ds.Clear();
da.Fill(ds);
dgvViolation.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

and the data will dispaly in datagridview like this :

```
name   company startdate enddate   days
---------------------------------------
john   IBM     12/2/2012 20/2/2012 5    
steven IBM     1/2/2012  12/2/2012 -3
```

I need the datagridview to display the positive values that appear in the days columns only.  How do I do this?

Comment: [Math.Abs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx.aspx)? Btw, that exists also in T-SQL as [ABS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)-function.

Comment: Do you want to filter on the database server (so `ds` only contains positive values) or on the client (so displaying only a subset of the content of `ds`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just change your SQL command to return the values above 0?

But if you want to do it with all the data returned, you can use the RowDataBound event of the gridview, something like this:

```
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //look at the value of the days column and use e.Row.Style["Display"] = "none"; to hide it.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the query to

```
"SELECT name,company,startdate,enddate,DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),enddate) AS days FROM Person WHERE days > 0"
```

Comment: "SELECT name,company,startdate,enddate,DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),enddate) AS days FROM Person WHERE DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),enddate) > 0"